# PHP reoder an array of arrays of similar objects into array of arrays of all dictinct objects where one type of object appears only once

Tags: php, arrays, slice

I want to get the column slices of the array of arrays.

Example:

```
Array (

[0]: Red1, Red2, Red3.
[1]: Green1, Green2, Green3, Green4, Green5.
[2]: Blue1, Blue2, Blue3, Blue4.
[3]: Yellow1, Yellow2, Yellow3.

)
```

to

```
Array(

[0]: Red1, Green1, Blue1, Yellow1.
[1]: Red2, Green2, Blue2, Yellow2.
[2]: Red3, Green3, Blue3, Yellow3.
[3]: Green4, Blue4.
[4]: Green5.

)
```

I can achieve this using two for loops but it does not seem like a good solution. Is there a more elegant / better way of doing this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$a= [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3],[1,2]];
$arr=[];
foreach($a as $key => $val ) {
   $count = count($val);        
   for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
      $arr[$i][]= $val[$i];
   }
}
print_r($arr);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 [2] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 2 [2] => 2 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 3 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 4 ) )
```

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response. This solution does seem like it would work but the question specifies that it can be done using two for loops and I'm looking for a way to achieve this in a more elegant way.